# OData value (color) applied to SAPUI5 table

Tags: text, colors, styles, sapui5

I wanted to know if the following is possible:

I've got an oData which has two fields related with colors

Colors are set as RGB because I thought it would be easier to pick them up to use it as styles in frontend.

I have a table in which I want to assign these colors to a specific cell, depending on 'ORGNA'.

I would like the row to have background-color red where Especialidad="UROLOGIA" (for example), but that color must come from the OData values I've got stored(see first image).

'ORGNA' values are the ones shown as 'Especialidad' (which means that 39ONC would be shown as 'Oncologia' and so on in the table).

I also wanted to know if this is possible or they must be set specifically from a Styles.css file.

Maybe there's some property like setColor or is there any way to add a background-color tag inside my XML View passing that OData values?

If you need any additional code, please just let me know.

Comment: Do the collors need to be those exact rbg values? sap.ui.core.ValueState provides red, yellow and green as colors. It would color the text not cell itself though. https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.71.39/#/entity/sap.m.ObjectStatus/sample/sap.m.sample.ObjectStatus

Comment: Yep, they need to be those values because it's a project... I know it would be easier to apply ValueState colors, but that's not what I'm exactly looking for

Comment: Sapui5 does not like it when developers set colors directly. They would much rather would want you to use semantic colors which can be redefined through themes, as the  Fiori design guidelines recommend. Which is why there is no way in the API to set explicit color values for pretty much anything.